# How to add undo/redo feature into android drawing app?

Tags: android

I want to add undo & redo feature to the finger paint, does anyone got ideas?
it is suitable to use in finger paint of android API demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to record your drawing steps, such as using an array of Paths every time a new path is drawn. When the undo button is pressed, you decrease your "draw counter" by one and redraw all the paths up to your "draw counter". When you redo, increase your "draw counter" by one and redraw all the paths up to the counter (or end of the array, naturally!). And after undoing and then drawing anew, remove the later entries from the draw array.

Comment: currentStack = new ArrayList<DrawPath>();

Comment: You're welcome. ;) If this is a successful answer, plese click the Tick icon on the left to mark it as such. Then I feel like I've achieved something today. :D